# /usr/bin/docker-current: Error: image library/openface-cambridge:latest not found

Tags: centos, docker

How should run this [docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/benbuleong/openface-cambridge/)?

```
[jalal@goku openface]$ sudo docker pull benbuleong/openface-cambridge
[sudo] password for jalal:
Using default tag: latest
Trying to pull repository docker.io/benbuleong/openface-cambridge ...
latest: Pulling from docker.io/benbuleong/openface-cambridge
d5c6f90da05d: Pull complete
1300883d87d5: Pull complete
c220aa3cfc1b: Pull complete
2e9398f099dc: Pull complete
dc27a084064f: Pull complete
e6520e4da641: Pull complete
c8d8c7a54713: Pull complete
bc4851bdea43: Pull complete
e6ecc295805c: Pull complete
5b22d5000650: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:61a5555124ee1af0629d51e78c60cc43d683da1ac8520605882034a1e8b058d0
[jalal@goku openface]$ sudo docker run -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -t -i openface-cambridge /bin/bash
Unable to find image 'openface-cambridge:latest' locally
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/openface-cambridge ...
Pulling repository docker.io/library/openface-cambridge
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error: image library/openface-cambridge:latest not found.
See '/usr/bin/docker-current run --help'.
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem:

```
[jalal@goku scratch]$ sudo docker run -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -t -i benbuleong/openface-cambridge /bin/bash
```